# Snackbar.setAnchorView(NOTWORKING);

Tags: java, android

This code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CoordinatorLayout root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        Snackbar.make(root, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAnchorView(navView).show();
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Main content -->

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

is not working for me. The Snackbar is still showing underneath the bottom navigation view. Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug?

Comment: set `Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT`

Comment: I don't think that's going to help out here my guy.